# Make `minmax` take whichever is smaller from a `px` or `fr` max value

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a sidebar that has a minimum-width of `200px` and a maximum of whichever is smaller out of `3fr` and `300px`, and would like it to tend toward the smallest value it can be. The closest behaviour to what I'd like is `minmax(200px, 3fr)`, but `3fr` will continue to grow above `300px` . I think what I'd *like* is `minmax(3fr, 300px)`, but `fr`s aren't allowed as the first argument to `minmax`. Is there a way to do this without a media query?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 3fr) 9fr; // this is what I want up till c. 1200px wide
  // grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) 9fr; // this makes the sidebar too wide until c. 1200px wide
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  background: hotpink;
}

.main {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet vitae quae nostrum quisquam eveniet laboriosam iste repudiandae provident saepe minima, modi nesciunt accusamus, quia inventore ratione quo beatae consectetur sapiente?</div>
  <div class="main"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum voluptas velit doloribus ipsam, nesciunt quibusdam veniam aut quas qui, mollitia laudantium enim explicabo eaque tenetur? Labore quibusdam maiores dolorem exercitationem!</p>
  <p>Ex adipisci aperiam voluptas veritatis aspernatur perspiciatis nihil impedit blanditiis neque aliquam nemo minima at, voluptates facere. Dicta exercitationem explicabo quasi ea facilis iusto, laudantium quibusdam veritatis animi provident culpa!</p>
  <p>Aut magni soluta amet eveniet quaerat in dignissimos mollitia accusantium architecto repellendus minima quos porro accusamus saepe consectetur corporis numquam, reprehenderit nulla enim fugiat. Illo ipsa mollitia aliquam enim illum?</p>
  <p>Odio rem minus accusamus deleniti, laboriosam voluptates dicta quia. Dolores nostrum voluptates eius odio aut maiores! Repellat nisi dolor laborum aspernatur ipsam? Quam quos hic est beatae blanditiis error sapiente?</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis nostrum iusto delectus modi excepturi facere quisquam, cupiditate animi ducimus? Numquam, labore officia, ad sapiente quo quos tempora minima repudiandae perspiciatis facere ullam, distinctio molestias expedita magni dolore dolores?</p>
  <p>Laudantium quos at adipisci! Doloribus obcaecati nulla, voluptates repellat impedit sed libero nam debitis ad cum molestias adipisci illum modi laborum? Sit vero corporis adipisci dolore repellendus alias soluta quam!</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fr` unit doesn't actually represent a length. It represents remaining space.

So saying you want the lesser of `px` or `fr` is kind of like apples and oranges.

`fr` can't be determined until all actual lengths have been rendered.

You may be able to work this out using a combination of `minmax()` at the container level, and `min-width` / `max-width` at the item level.

For example:

> The closest behaviour to what I'd like is `minmax(200px, 3fr)`, but `3fr` will continue to grow above `300px`.

So what about:

```
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 3fr) 9fr;
}

.sidebar {
   max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. I couldn't see the wood for the trees! Thank you.

Comment: …however, I think the problem with this is that once the sidebar reaches 300px wide, it doesn't grow itself, but the grid area it sits within still grows (creating a gap between the .sidebar and the .main at larger widths.

Comment: I figured. You're going to have to try different combinations. Maybe using `min-content` or `max-content` values. Or, it may not be possible with Grid Level 1 alone.

Comment: I'm starting to think it might require a media-query. Which is no bad thing. Just wanted to check that I wasn't missing something.